# upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream - Jetty

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using Spring boot application with embedded Jetty.

> Spring boot version - 2.2.1.RELEASE
> Jetty Version - 9.4.25.v20191220

Applications are running on multiple hosts(Say 5 hosts) and with a load balancer in front of it.

**Load balancer setting:-**

```
Keep Alive conections - 20
Keepalive Timeout - 60s
```

**Jetty Settings**

```
  server.jetty.connection-idle-timeout=62000  (62 Secs)
```

Load balancer is throwing 502 sometime with the logs below.

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ******, server: xyz.test.com, request: "GET /health/check HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://XXXXX:8443/health/check", host: "xyz.test.com" 

upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ******, server: xyz.test.com, request: "GET /api/v1/weather/2485 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://XXXXXX:8443/api/v1/weather/2485", host: "xyz.test.com"
```

We are using all default setting for Spring boot embedded Jetty. Is there anything config to be changed?

We have not enabled access log on the server side and no logs related to 502 in our logs.

Comment: Not enough information to work with.  What do the jetty logs on the server side show for those same connections that caused this prematurely closed situation?  Also, you might want to set the load balancer to have a keepalive timeout which is lower then the server side idle timeout, otherwise the load balancer will use dead connections.

Comment: We are using the default default Jetty setting. Not sure what is the default value for idle timeout. Will check.

Comment: Nice to see the bounty, but nobody can answer this with the scant information you have provided.  More details are needed.  eg: detailed logs, precise versions (of jetty as saying "spring boot 2.2.1" means only a minimum version of jetty), exact values of configurables (idle timeout default values have changed many times over the years, in both spring and jetty, and they can even change depending on the runtime environment, if you don't know the values, then set them to a known value).

Comment: Have added the jetty version and the idle timeout setting. No specific logs related to 502 and any error on the server logs. Do you need any specific log?